# Tabular multicolumns and multirows displacement (and vertical line separation)

Tags: tables, adjustbox, vertical

I have a huge problem with formatting my tabular latex table with multicolumns and multirows. Specifically with vertical line separation and centering the last section. I'm pretty new in tables so feel free to give me any piece of advice which can help with it.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{float, enumitem, amsmath} 
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multicol, multirow, threeparttable, tabularx, subcaption, booktabs, colortbl, color}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{belowskip=-5pt}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\onecolumn
\begin{table} \centering
\caption{Simple caption.}
\label{tab:setTag}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.9\textwidth,center=\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l|lcc@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries Results} & \bfseries Method 1 & \bfseries Method 2 \\
\midrule
& &\multicolumn{2}{c}{First section}\\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
\multirow{14}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~Description 1}}& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \cmidrule{3-4}

& &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Second section}\\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \cmidrule{3-4}

& &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Third section}\\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \cmidrule{3-4} 

\rowcolor{gray!10}
& &\multicolumn{2}{c}{First section}\\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
\rowcolor{gray!10}
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
\rowcolor{gray!10}
& &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Second section}\\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
\rowcolor{gray!10}
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
\rowcolor{gray!10}
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
\rowcolor{gray!10}
& &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Third section}\\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
\rowcolor{gray!10}
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
\rowcolor{gray!10}
\multirow{-8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~Description 2}}& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \cmidrule{3-4}

& &\multicolumn{2}{c}{First section}\\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
\multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~Description 3}}& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
\cmidrule{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

- Rules defined in `booktabs` package has small gape above and below rule, consequently the are not intended for table with vertical lines.
- It is not clear, why your table you use the `threeparttable` when you not use any its features.
- I would not use `scalebox`, better is use table environment for example as is `tabularx` where you can prescribe table width. With use its `X` column type the text in cells in such column is automatic break into more lines (well, this you can obtain with `p{<width>}` columns too).
- Instead of switch from `\twocolumn` document to `\onecolumn` (and than back again) is better to use `table*` float environment. Using it, table will appear on the top of the next page from where is inserted in the text.

```
\documentclass[final,5p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{float, enumitem, amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}     % new
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{} % new
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% changed, instead of color, colortbl
%\usepackage{adjustbox} % not used in this MWE
%\usepackage{todonotes} % not used in this MWE

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{belowskip=-5pt}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
%\usepackage{subcaption} % not used in this MWE

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*} 
    \centering
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Description 3 }
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\caption{Simple caption.}
\label{tab:setTag}
%\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.9\textwidth,center=\textwidth}
%\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l | l *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \Xhline{1pt}
    & \thead[l]{Results} 
        & \thead{Method 1} & \thead{Method 2}           \\
    \Xhline{0.7pt}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First section}             \\ 
    \Xcline{3-4}{0.6pt}
\multirow{16}{*}{\rothead{Description 1}}
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \Xcline{3-4}{0.6pt}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Second section}             \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \Xcline{3-4}{0.6pt}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Third section}             \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \Xcline{3-4}{0.7pt}
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First section}             \\
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \Xcline{3-4}{0.7pt}
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    &   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Second section}             \\ 
    \Xcline{3-4}{0.7pt}
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \Xcline{3-4}{0.7pt}
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    &   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Third section}          \\ 
    \Xcline{3-4}{0.6pt}
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
\multirow{-8}{*}{\rothead{Description 2}}
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
%    \Xcline{3-4}{0.7pt}
%    &   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{First section}      \\ 
%    \Xcline{3-4}{0.7pt}
%\multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~Description 3}}
%    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
%    \Xcline{3-4}{0.7pt}
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}
%\end{threeparttable}
%\end{adjustbox}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
A possible solution or third part of table, where instead of "Description 3" in the first column is used abbreviation "D. 3". Association to their meaning is given with "Description 1 (D. 1)" and  "Description 2 (D. 2)" in the first two parts of table.

```
\documentclass[final,5p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{float, enumitem, amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{belowskip=-5pt}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*} 
    \centering
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Description 3 (D. 3)}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\caption{Simple caption.}
\label{tab:setTag}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l | l *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \Xhline{1pt}
    & \thead[l]{Results} 
        & \thead{Method 1} & \thead{Method 2}           \\
    \Xhline{0.7pt}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First section}             \\ 
    \Xcline{3-4}{0.6pt}
\multirow{16}{*}{\rothead{Description 1 (D.\,1)}}
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \Xcline{3-4}{0.6pt}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Second section}             \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \Xcline{3-4}{0.6pt}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Third section}             \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    \Xcline{3-4}{0.7pt}
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First section}             \\
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \Xcline{3-4}{0.8pt}
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    &   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Second section}             \\ 
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \Xcline{3-4}{0.8pt}
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    &   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Third section}          \\ 
\rowcolor{gray!10}
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
\rowcolor{gray!10}
\multirow{-8}{*}{\rothead{Description 2 (D.\,2)}}
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
    \Xcline{3-4}{0.6pt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont(D.\,3)} % <--- changed (reduced) \rothead size
\multirow{2}{*}{\rothead{(D.\,3)}}
    &   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{First section}      \\ 
    & Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\[1.5ex]
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much Zarko! almost there. I can handle with Xline under specific section (Fist/Second/First) but do you have any idea how to solve the issue with Description 3 section where is only one subsection (describe in the bottom of the photo)?

Comment: @Dominika, this was not clear to me. I thought that you didn’t write all the rows of your table, so that part of table I omitted. You certainly can't insert "Description 3" in the height of one table row because that word is just too long. You can add blank rows, or use an abbreviation instead, such as "D 3.

Comment: to answer some of your thoughts: I believe that I used threeparttable features in my thesis when it comes to pretty long caption but in the MWE no (I probably forgot to delete it so my mistake, so sorry). Scalebox was the first idea and stuck with me but I'm happy to try your suggestion with tabularx. Previously I have some trouble with tabularx environment when I have a lot of headers - not text in the cell - and I can't handle with fit these headers in A4 wide.

Comment: And the last thought - I don't use 2 columns environment but I have very long .cls file with specific option to my document and I want put here whole self-enclosed MWE example so I used the first type of document which I found on overleafs templates.

Comment: Yes, the blank rows are the good starting point - I will try.

Comment: Dear @Dominika, my crystal ball is still not recover from Covid 19 ... :-(, so can't see what is your document actually is. I only can use information which you provide in question. And from there follows, that your document has two columns. However, if it is one column, you only need to erase * at `table*`. I will edit my answer with some new proposition for your table asap.

Comment: @Dear Zarko, I wish I had a crystal ball :) I understood - for future question I will be aware of it, again, I apologise and thank you for your time, really appreciate it. Solution is right now awesome.

Comment: sorry for bother you, but maybe you know smart way to align whole data to specific sign? I mean mathematic sign like '\pm' - in equation exist very handful and easy to use 'split' function with '&' command inserted where you want to align other equations. I read something about 'angle' in table environment, but this doesn't suit to my solution (or even more probably scenario - I can't use it correctly).

Comment: @Dominika, if I understood you correctly, you looking for `S` column type, defined in the `siunitx` package, or for `D` column type defined in the `dcolumn` package. For more/better  help, please ask new question where provide example of table, with which you have problems.

Comment: sure, thank you. Just created new one issue :)

Comment: @Dominika, now I added a possible solution for the last part of table (Description 3). Maybe you'll like it.

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 4.0) is compatible with `booktabs`.

You can do all the blocks (`\multicolumn` and `multirow`) with `\Block`).

You can color your rows with only one instruction `[code-before = \rowcolor{gray!10}{18-25}]`

You can rule whatever rule you want at the end using Tikz and the nodes created by `nicematrix` under the array.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{wc{5mm}LCC}[code-before = \rowcolor{gray!10}{18-25}]
\toprule
& \bfseries Results & \bfseries Method 1 & \bfseries Method 2 \\
\midrule
& &\Block{1-2}{First section}\\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
\Block{14-1}{\rotate Description 1}
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \cmidrule{3-4}
%
& &\Block{1-2}{Second section}\\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \cmidrule{3-4}
%
& &\Block{1-2}{Third section}\\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
%
\Block{8-1}{\rotate Description 2}& &\Block{1-2}{First section}\\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
%
& &\Block{1-2}{Second section}\\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
%
& &\Block{1-2}{Third section}\\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\
& Very long name & Something pretty long too & Something else even longer than before \\ \bottomrule
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw (row-1-|col-2) -- (row-26-|col-2) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of above code]

Comment: It seems that `NiceTabular` will become serious competitor in table design options :-)! +1!

Comment: @Zarko: I try to improve the package... :-)

Comment: @F.Pantigny when I try put this MWE to overleafs for quick view the difference between these two solutions I had a lot of errors message with 'environment NiceTabular undefined' even if I added '\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}' to my preamble. any advice?

Comment: @Dominika: As I wrote, you need a very recent version of  `nicematrix` (v. 4.0 of 2020/05/08) and that version needs a very recent version of `expl3` (LaTeX3 programming layer which is now included in the LaTeX format itself). That means that you need a up-to-date version of LaTeX (e.g. TeXLive 2020). I think that `Overleaf` is still at TeXLive 2019. So you can't use it with `Overleaf`. Maybe in one year...

Comment: @F.Pantigny thank you for clarification. I will try maybe in Texmaker. Can I do with nicetab align with mathematical signs? Like, let's suppose I have one column with '+/-' sign which should be aligned to the left of columns and all the values in each cell should be aligned to '+/-' sign. Can I do it easier than siunitx which completely destroy my table...

Comment: @Dominika: I'm not sure to understand the question. You should ask another question on this forum. `nicematrix` is compatible with the `S` columns of `siunitx`. There is probably a mean to do what you want with `S` columns without destroying the array.

Comment: @F.Pantigny I've created one but with tabularx solution but like I said before I've tried Nicetabular in Texmaker and the only things which I changed in yours MWE are: `{wc{5mm}L{SS}}[code-before = \rowcolor{gray!10}{18-25}]` and `{\bfseries Method 1} & {\bfseries Method 2}` and of course provide new data which is for columns Method 1 and Method 2 numbers like exp. `$11,5(5)$ & $444,34(719)$` -> although I get a lot of errors msg. Do you have any idea what should I add to make it run? My example error `"missing number, treated as zero (...) \toprule"`.

Comment: @Dominica: write `{wc{5mm}LSS}` instead of `{wc{5mm}L{SS}}`

Comment: In this answer, since version 5.0 of `nicematrix` one must write `lcc` instead of `LCC` in the preamble of `{NiceTabular}` (but there is an option for backward compatibility).