# Alignment in tabularx using exp. siunitx

Tags: align, tabularx, siunitx

It's never ending story about that -> [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547531/tabular-multicolumns-and-multirows-displacement-and-vertical-line-separation/547554?noredirect=1#comment1383089_547554). Simply, I just want to align to 'pm' sign my number columns. I've already tried replacing headers `{l | l *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}` with `{l | l l l *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}` and than to check one column with siunitx: `{l | l S[table-align-uncertainty, separate-uncertainty=true] l l *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}` but it doesn't work at all.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float, enumitem, amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{} 
\usepackage{colortbl, color} %I preffer that instead of xcolor because xcolor give me errors with beamer
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{belowskip=-5pt}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}

\begin{document}

   \begin{table} 
    \centering
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Description 3 }
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\caption{Simple caption.}
\label{tab:setTag}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l | l *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \Xhline{1pt}
    & \thead[l]{Results} 
        & \thead{Method 1} & \thead{Method 2}           \\
    \Xhline{0.7pt}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First section}             \\ 
    \Xcline{3-4}{0.6pt}
\multirow{3}{*}{\rothead{Description 1}}
    &Very long name & $11,5 \pm 0,5$ & $444,34 \pm 71,9$ \\
    & Very long name & $109,2 \pm 75,3$ & $2,8 \pm 664,36$ \\
    & Very long name& $9438 \pm 8$ & $256,0 \pm 98,1$ \\
    & Very long name & $11,5 \pm 0,5$ & $444,34 \pm 71,9$ \\
    & Very long name & $109,2 \pm 75,3$ & $2,8 \pm 664,36$ \\
    & Very long name & $9438 \pm 8$ & $256,0 \pm 98,1$ \\
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I've changed header to `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l | X S[table-align-uncertainty, separate-uncertainty=true] S[table-align-uncertainty, separate-uncertainty=true]*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}}}` and data from first row to `11,5(5) & 444,34(719` and I get that result (strange Methods headers):

[image]

---

I've now had errors with *array package '>{}' at wrong position*. Can someone please tell me which one is the correct one? And another one with *'missing # inserted in alignment preamble'* and the third one *'missing $ inserted'* but I don't know why because it shows line with `\end{tabularx}`.

New part of the code:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l | X S[table-align-uncertainty, separate-uncertainty=true] S[table-align-uncertainty, separate-uncertainty=true]*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}}}
    \Xhline{1pt}
    & \thead[l]{Results} 
        & {\thead{Method 1}} & {\thead{Method 2}}           \\
    \Xhline{0.7pt}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First section}             \\ 
    \Xcline{3-4}{0.6pt}
\multirow{3}{*}{\rothead{Description 1}}
    &Very long name & $11,5(5)$ & $444,34(719)$ \\
    & Very long name & $109,2(753)$ & $2,8(63)$ \\
    & Very long name& $9438(8)$ & $256,0(981)$ \\
    &Very long name & $11,5(5)$ & $444,34(719)$ \\
    & Very long name & $109,2(753)$ & $2,8(63)$ \\
    & Very long name& $9438(8)$ & $256,0(981)$ \\
    \end{tabularx}
```

It shows (which is obviously not align):

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: If you want 11,5 \pm 0,5 as the output in an `S` type columns of the table, you should use `11,5(5)` as the input in the `S` type column.

Comment: Why do you use `tabularx` here? Your table is already narrow enough to fit into the textwidth. By using `tabularx` here you only stretch the table introducing unneccessary white space.

Comment: @leandriis my whole table is much wider (the name of the columns etc.) but for the MWE and just align operation it is not necessary to provide the whole one (in the previous post I showed how huge the table is) :)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. I was a bit confused since the dummy text you included in your previous example is something entirely different than numbers with their uncertainties which you showed in this example code.

Comment: I know, so sorry - just learning how to quick describe problem with as much information as I can gave. So, my 'real table' has very long 'Results' section and in some of the 'First section'/'Second section' etc. a lot of numbers data.

Comment: If the "Results"  column is the column that contains the most text (and would need linebreaks in order to ensure the table still fits into the textwidth) you might want to use the `X` type column for the "Results"  column instead of the `l` type column you currently use. Do not use `X` type columns for yolumns that just contain numbers of single words.

Comment: I see, so it should be {l | X *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}}} like this? But the problem with aligment still exist.

Comment: From the text in your question I assume you just replaced the column specifiers to include an `S` type column without explicitly adapting the contents of the table itself. In my very first comment I already hinted on why simply using an `S` type column will not work in this specific case as the `S` type column expects numbers with uncertainties to be input in a special format.

Comment: @leandriis please see my updates

Comment: Did you get any error messages from your code? If so, please do not look at the output. Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error. I guess, you recieved an error like "Extra }, or forgotten $.". If so, surround the `\thead` commands in the `S` type columns in a set of `{}` as in `{\thead{Method 1}} `. Text or other non-number contents in `S` type columns must be placed inside a set  of `{}.

Comment: @leandriis okay, I have errors but they odd to me. I putted new part of the code in main post

Comment: even more troubles I have with aligment not only a 'pm' sign, but also numbers with minus and the fact that all the numbers are different, I mean one time I've used 0,05 and another time -8738.

Comment: Regarding: `array package '>{}' at wrong position`: Remove `*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}}` entirely. You already have 4 columns.

Comment: Regarding: `Missing $ inserted.`:  Remove all `$`s in `S` type columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float, enumitem, amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{} 
\usepackage{colortbl, color} %I preffer that instead of xcolor because xcolor give me errors with beamer

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{belowskip=-5pt}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-align-uncertainty, separate-uncertainty=true}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l | X S[table-format=4.1(3)] S[table-format=3.2(5)]}
    \Xhline{1pt}
    & \thead[l]{Results} 
        & {\thead{Method 1}} & {\thead{Method 2}}           \\
    \Xhline{0.7pt}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First section}             \\ 
    \Xcline{3-4}{0.6pt}
\multirow{3}{*}{\rothead{Description 1}}
    & Very long name & 11,5(5)    & 444,34(7190) \\
    & Very long name & 109,2(753) & 2,80(66436)  \\
    & Very long name & 9438(8)    & 256,0(981)   \\
    & Very long name & 11,5(5)    & 444,34(7190) \\
    & Very long name & 109,2(753) & 2,80(66436)  \\
    & Very long name & 9438(8)    & 256,0(981)   \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, aligment works pretty well but rotated column looking very bad now (I've changed yours `\multirow{3}{*}{\rothead{Description 1}}` to `\multirow{6}{*}{\rothead{Description 1}}`, but it doesn't help

Comment: besides rotating text issue I also putted in description example how some of the numbers looks like. The +/- symbol is too close to them - please take a look (last image).

Comment: thank you so much, you also help me a lot with better understanding tables!

Comment: If you want to add numbers with more than 1 decimal place into the first column, you will have to adjust the table-format option of this specific column accordingly. In order to add a short horizontal line in a S type column, use {--} instead of - -.

Comment: Got it, but when I put `S[table-format=4.10(5)]` or `S[table-format=4.1(100)]` or `S[table-format=400.1(5)]` it's just ridiculous and nasty. How it works?

Comment: Also I have the last three rows something like `Some text about some things: 6949,00009 +/- 0,00008` and I think that I cannot combine `S` type column with mixed numbers and words? Or how to do it?

Comment: okay, I set 2.4(7) and it works fine, but still the last few rows with text and numbers overlaps even if I put text in braces {}

Answer (score 3):

just answering your comment under leandriis answer, you can simply rotate the text directly there is no need for a multirow, also as I commented previously in chat I would never use tabularx for a table of data like this, tabularx is all about tables of *text* and line breaking in columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float, enumitem, amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{} 
\usepackage{colortbl, color} %I preffer that instead of xcolor because xcolor give me errors with beamer

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{belowskip=-5pt}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-align-uncertainty, separate-uncertainty=true}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l | l S[table-format=4.1(3)] S[table-format=3.2(5)]}
    \Xhline{1pt}
    & \thead[l]{Results} 
        & {\thead{Method 1}} & {\thead{Method 2}}           \\
    \Xhline{0.7pt}
\smash{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{\bfseries Description 1}}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First section}             \\ 
    \Xcline{3-4}{0.6pt}
    & Very long name & 11,5(5)    & 444,34(7190) \\
    & Very long name & 109,2(753) & 2,80(66436)  \\
    & Very long name & 9438(8)    & 256,0(981)   \\
    & Very long name & 11,5(5)    & 444,34(7190) \\
    & Very long name & 109,2(753) & 2,80(66436)  \\
    & Very long name & 9438(8)    & 256,0(981)   \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will be remember that, thank you for your time but I put `Description 1` in multirow because I want to forced this text to be centered. In original table I have 16 rows (like my first post here, linked in description) so I think centered looks better

Comment: @Dominika you can easily move it down, just put it in a later row or add an \hspace after the `1` multirow desn't force vertical centering

Comment: Of course - that's not a problem with odd number, but I will try. Once again thank you so much for your time and advices.

Comment: @Dominika actually you should accept lenadriis answer that had better siunitx use than the answer I was going to give, which was your main question, I just stole the entire code from that answer to add this extra comment, I'll feel a bit bad if I steal the points as well:-)

Comment: Okay, right - I apologise. I've already changed, but thank you for your both :) Now I will try to use it in the much bigger table, hope it will work. Fingers crossed!

Comment: I'm sorry but @David it shows a lot of problems with numbers like 0,0009+/-0,0001. It looks like everything overlaps each other...

Comment: And previously when the cell was empty I simply put `--`, but now it doesn't work. Can you help me figure it out why?

Comment: it's using a format of 4.1 if you have 4 decimal places that needs to be 4.4 or some such, use `{--}` the braces hide non numeric entries from siunitx @Dominika

Comment: I set `{Some text:} 0,62405(65)` but it still overlaps.

Comment: I believe it puts 0,62405 +/- 0,00065 like in any other case. And I've changed to `2.5(7)`